# Join two tables on a specific table fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two tables **activity_log** and **user_followers**. I have to join these two tables and get the activity of a user with the user activity that he is following (let's say user_id 6 is following user_id 4). But the below query only returning the activity of the user having the id of 6. I want to get the activity of the user with the id of 6 plus the activity of the user he is following.

**Query**

```
SELECT activity_log.* 
FROM activity_log 
    join user_followers ON activity_log.user_id = user_followers.follow_id
        AND activity_log.user_id = 6;
```

**activity_log:**

[image]

**user_followers:**
[image]

Comment: You don't explain us what is your problem? Is there any error? May be you got some unexpected result? please be more specific

Comment: If you just wanted to brag that is what a Twitter account is for. Unless you are having a problem you didn't mention?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want user_id 6's activity plus activity of users he's following.  That would be:

```
SELECT activity_log.* 
FROM activity_log 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_followers 
  ON activity_log.user_id = user_followers.follow_id
WHERE (activity_log.user_id = 6 OR ISNULL(user_followers.user_id,0) = 6);
```

The LEFT OUTER is used in case user_id 6 has no followers.

Comment: I got this error when run your query
`SQL Error (1582): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'`

Comment: Did you forget the comma zero at the end?  ISNULL(user_followers.user_id,**0**)